# How to handle multiple text values in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
handleText=e=>{
    this.setState({
      text : e.target.value
    })
  }

<div class="col-ps-6 firstname">
                   <label>First Name*</label>
                   <div class="text-box">
                       <input type="text" onChange={this.handleText} id="inputText"/>
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-ps-6 lastname">
                  <label>Last name</label>
                  <div class="text-box">
                      <input type="text" onChange1={this.handleText} id="inputText"/>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-ps-6 emailid">
                  <label>Email Id*</label>
                  <div class="text-box">
                      <input type="text" onChange2={this.handleText} id="inputText"/>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-ps-6 mobile">
                  <label>Mobile number</label>
                  <div class="text-box">
                      <input type="text" onChange3={this.handleText} id="inputText"/>
                  </div>
              </div>

it is handling only one value. how to write an event for multiple values
it is handling only one value. how to write an event for multiple values
it is handling only one value. how to write an event for multiple values
it is handling only one value. how to write an event for multiple value
```

Comment: Your `state` needs a property for each controlled input. Then you use currying: `handleText = field => e => this.setState({ [field]: e.target.value });` Now you can use `onChange={this.handleText("email")}`

Comment: i am very munch new to this, i understood about onchange event,i am confused about writing handletext event, can u show example with one field for handletext

Answer (score 1):

It's a common practice in `react` to handle input changes. You should provide a `name` attribute of your `input` fields. Then make your `handleText` function like:

```
handleText = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
}
```

Please make sure that your `state` object's properties are exactly same as the input field's name attributes.

For example, if you have two input fields then the `jsx` would be like:

```
<input type='text' name='first_name' onChange={this.handleText} value={this.state.first_name} />
<input type='text' name='last_name' onChange={this.handleText} value={this.state.last_name} />
```

And your `state` would be:

```
this.state = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many approaches to this, the simplest one to understand:

```
handleText=(key, value)=>{
    this.setState({
        [key] : value
    })
}

        <input type="text" 
            onChange={(e) => this.handleText('firstname',e.target.value)} 
            id="inputText"
            value={this.state.firstname}
        />

        <input type="text" 
            onChange={(e) => this.handleText('lastname',e.target.value)} 
            id="inputText"
            value={this.state.lastname}
        />
```

Here what I am doing is passing both the key and values for the state, based on the input field.